# Error in upgrading codeigniter from 3.1.3 to 3.1.4

Tags: codeigniter, ubuntu

I have recently upgrade CodeIgniter from 3.1.3 to 3.1.4, now gives me this error

> Warning:
>   require_once(/opt/lampp/htdocs/social/system/core/CodeIgniter.php):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/social/index.php on line 315
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
>   '/opt/lampp/htdocs/social/system/core/CodeIgniter.php'
>   (include_path='.:/opt/lampp/lib/php') in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/social/index.php on line 315

I am using ubuntu 16

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click on system folder in codeginater then click on permission tab 
it will show three types of groups owner , group , others

The Owner is the usually the creator of the files/folders. In Linux, files or folders that you created in your Home directory are usually owned by you, unless you specifically change the ownership.

The Group contains a group of users who share the same permissions and user privilege.

Others means the general public.

As for permissions, there are 3 type of actions that you can perform on a file/folder. You can either read, write or execute.

Read – You can only view the file, but cannot modify the content of the file. When applied on Folder, you can only view the files in the folder, but you can’t delete from or add files into the folder.

Write – You can edit and modify the file. For Folders, you can delete and add files into the folder.

Execute – Execute is mainly used when you need to run the file (commonly used when you need to run a script).

give the full access to others and groups.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for reply, Now I am trying it.